# nicEdit - HTML editing on a Bootstrap popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg

I'm having a problem when I open a nicEdit instance inside a Bootstrap popup.

I can edit my text just fine, the only thing that isn't working properly is the edit HTML popup. The HTML shows up fine on the textarea but I can't click or edit it. The other buttons on that popup (close and submit) work fine, so the only problem is the textarea.

I've tried setting a higher z-index for the textarea, but that didn't help.

Anyone had this problem?

EDIT: Sorry, here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MXkY3/1/

The HTML button is not visible because the image file isn't included, but it's the only button available.

I'm initializing the editor normally:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    new nicEditor({
        buttonList: ['xhtml']
    }).panelInstance('new_page_content18');
});
```

And the CSS for the popup is the Bootstrap standard. But you can see that the popup generated after the HTML click isn't editable.

EDIT2: The problem isn't with showing the HTML popup, the problem is editing the HTML inside the textarea of that popup. I can't even select text.

Comment: put your code into http://jsfiddle.net/ and send it back, then we can help. Mods will remove your question if it doesn't have helpful input from the asker!

Comment: Check for if `textarea` is not disabled. And check for errors by Inspect Element.

Comment: AlexHighHigh, sorry, edited the original post.

Comment: Anup, no errors, the textarea is enabled, that's why I thought it was a z-index problem.

Comment: No issues here. Your fiddle is working fine for me on Chrome/Firfox/IE9 - Win7

Comment: So have you already solved it [with version 1](http://jsfiddle.net/MXkY3/1/)? (btw works for me as well in Win7/IE11)

Comment: Weird, for me it isn't working, nor it is for the client. I'm on OS X  10.8 with Chrome, and the client is on Vista with Chrome...

Comment: The problem isn't showing the popup with the HTML, the problem is editing the HTML inside the textarea.

Comment: Still haven't solved this.

Comment: I've ran into the same issue with JQuery UI Dialog

Comment: Know this is very old question but did you ever find a fix?

Comment: @Woody sorry for the delay, but no, never found a solution. Ended up pitching for using this textarea outside of the modal.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new event in the modal and validate html NicEdit.

```js
//...
$('.div-element-modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
 validarNicEditorEnModalOff();
});
$('.div-element-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
 validarNicEditorEnModal();
});
$('.div-element-modal').modal('show');

//...
function validarNicEditorEnModalOff() {
 $(".nicEdit-selectControl").each(function() {
  $(this).unbind("click");
 });
 $(".nicEdit-selectTxt").each(function() {
  $(this).unbind("click");
 });
 $(".nicEdit-pane").each(function() {
  $(this).parent().css("position", "absolute");
 });
}
function validarNicEditorEnModal() {
 $(".nicEdit-selectControl").each(function() {
  $(this).unbind("click");
 });
 $(".nicEdit-selectTxt").each(function() {
  $(this).unbind("click");
 });
 $(".nicEdit-selectControl").each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
     $(".nicEdit-pane").parent().css("position", "fixed");
    }, 200);
    return true;
  });
 });
 $(".nicEdit-selectTxt").each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
     $(".nicEdit-pane").parent().css("position", "fixed");
    }, 200);
    return true;
  });
 });
}
```

Regards